# What is the maximum value of $n$ if $4^n$ divides $1000!$ without a remainder?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial

> If $1000!$ is divided by $4^n$ with a remainder 0, what is the highest
>   possible value of $n$?

I placed 2, 3, 4, etc value in $n$ but didn't found any possible $4^n$. Moreover I have seen that only $4^1$ can divide 1000! without remainder. Is there any way to prove this or there are some possible $n$?

Comment: $1000!=1\times 2\times3\times...\times 999\times 1000$

Comment: @giannispapav I understood it. But can you please tell how can I get the highest value of $n$? I don't think calculator can find it.

Comment: Just apply [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) for $p=2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Legendre's Theorem](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LegendresTheorem.shtml) (which is a very useful tool for such problems)
$$\nu_p(n!)=\frac{n-s_p(n)}{p-1}$$
With $p=2$ and $n=1000$
$$\nu_2(1000!)=1000-s_2(1000)$$
Also 
$(1000)_{10}=(1111101000)_2$
so $s_2(1000)=1+1+1+1+1+0+1+0+0+0=6$, thus
$$\nu_2(1000!)=1000-6=994$$
or $$2^{994}=4^{497} \mid 1000!$$

Answer (score 3):

For a solution by hand: $1000!$ has

$500$ multiples of $2^{1}$

$250$ multiples of $2^{2}$

$125$ multiples of $2^{3}$

$62$ multiples of $2^{4}$

$31$ multiples of $2^{5}$

$15$ multiples of $2^{6}$

$7$ multiples of $2^{7}$

$3$ multiples of $2^{8}$

$1$ multiples of $2^{9}$

So $2^{1+3+7+15+...+500}=2^{994}=4^{497}|1000!$

Comment: The only thing missing is $2^0=4^0=1$ but I guess it doesn't matter, being an identity.

Comment: @poetasis But $2^0$ doesn't contribute a nontrivial power of $2$, does it? Could you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $125$ multiples of $2^3$?

Comment: @ giannispapav $2^0$ contributes a trivial power of two so it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @giannispavav can you please explain me how the exponent of 2 is related to n? Also How there are 500 multiples of $2^1$ in 1000!

Comment: @Shromi $1000!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot...\cdot999\cdot1000=(1\cdot3\cdot...\cdot999)\cdot(2\cdot4\cdot...\cdot1000)$

Comment: @giannispavav thanks for explaining this easily.