# $1000!$ is divisible by $4^a$, Find the highest value of $a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

As the question goes ,
I tried to solve for $2^{2a}$ first but all I got was a mess. If anyone could kindly solve this for me I would be grateful .

## **Edit** :

Thanks for the replies. I tried the problem on my own and went with this approach,

$1000! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot \dots \cdot 1000$

I want to solve for $2^{2a}$ first so I consider the even numbers only

Hence,

$$1000!=(2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8 \dots 1000) \cdot (1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 9 \cdot \dots 999)$$

Since, odd numbers cannot be factored by $2$, they will be ignored (in the following steps).

$$1000! = 2^{500}(1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot \dots \cdot 500) \\ = 2^{500}(2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 8 \cdot 10 \cdot \dots \cdot 500) \\ = 2^{500} \cdot 2^{250} \cdot (1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot \dots \cdot 250) \\ = 2^{500}2^{250}(2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 8 \cdot 10 \cdot \dots \cdot 250) \\ = 2^{500}2^{250}2^{125}(1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot \dots \cdot 125)$$

I repeat this process and what i get at the end is

$2^{500} \cdot 2^{250} \cdot 2^{125} \cdot 2^{62} 
\cdot 2^{31} \cdot 2^{15} \cdot 2^{7} \cdot 2^{3} \cdot 2^{1} = \mathbf{2^{994}}$

Therefore, the answer to the original question would be 497

Is this process correct?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Probably not what you meant: $a = \log_4(1000!)$.

Comment: Could you determine the valuation of $1000!$ with respect to the prime $p=2$ ? Then, the rest is easy.

Comment: My first thought: Same problem for $(2n)!$, small values of $n$. You get the sequence
$$
1,~3,~4,~7,~8,~10,~11,~15,~16,~18, \ldots
$$

Comment: The question itself is interesting. If the asker would show any effort at all in trying to answer it, I would probably upvote.

Comment: @AdamRubinson It would then still be an abstract duplictate. More annoying is that such questions are still answered.

Comment: @everyone I am sorry that I asked the question in such a vague manner . I am new to this thing so I didnt know how to ask the questions properly . I have now edited the question and added my method of trying to solve the question. If it is correct or if its wrong , let me know kindly .

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Peter can you provide a link to the duplicated question? If so, I'll vote to close.

Comment: Previous question about $1000!$ and base $4$: [What is the maximum value of $n$ if $4^n$ divides $1000!$ without a remainder?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3133488/89922)

Comment: @peterwhy It does. Thank you, could you check my process and see if it has any faults in it ?

Comment: No need to check my process the same process is at that question

Comment: @IftekharAlamBhuiyan I think your approach is good, until you wrote your "answer to the original question": the highest value of $a$ should be $\frac{994}2$, not the $4^{994/2}$ that you wrote.

Comment: Oh I see now , thanks for correcting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a number $n$, denote by $v_2(n)$ the highest power of 2 which divides it, such that $v_2(1) = 0$, and $v_2(2^k) = k$ and so on.

Then it is clear that $v_2(1000!) = \sum_{n=1}^{1000}v_2(n)$.

To count the latter, there is a simple trick one can use: write $v_2$ as a sum of indicators. Write $I_k(n) = 1$ if $2^k$ divides $n$ and $0$ otherwise.

Clearly,
$v_2 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}I_k$.

Now plug this identity into the previous sum:
$$v_2(1000!) = \sum_{n=1}^{1000}v_2(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{1000}I_k(n).$$

The inner summation is simply $[1000/2^k]$, hence the largest power of $2$ that divides $1000!$ is

$$[1000/2] + [1000/4] + ... + [1000/512]$$

This is something you can do by hand or plug in a calculator. The point is that it gives you a number $b$ which has the property that $2^b | 1000!$ but $2^{b+1}$ does not divide $1000!$.

The maximal $a$ for which $4^a | 1000!$ is then $[b/2]$.

Comment: Iftekhar, if you accept the answer, you should also upvote it.